# Displacent from velocity

Tags: integration

From the [acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration) of a [particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle), that is given as $a = 2t + 4$, I have worked out [velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) from [integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) as $V = t² + 4t + c$. The [displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(geometry)) of the object is 30 m after 3 s, how do I find $c$? I am also unsure what is meant by finding displacement in terms of [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_physics)?

Comment: You’ve been able to find _velocity_ in terms of time. What’s confusing you about finding displacement in terms of time?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like question in physics site, but this is simple, so whatever.

Your velocity at time 't' was derived by integrating acceleration at time 't' and constant 'c' was added as we don't know initial velocity, since acceleration only talks about change in velocity.

Here c is velocity at time **t=0**.

Similarly by integrating velocity, we get location at time 't' as

$X = \dfrac{t^3}{3}+2t^2+ct+k$

Here k is location at time **t=0**. In other words, initial location.

Displacement is net change in location of an object. Assuming our first point as **"t=0"**

So, displacement will be $Displacement =\dfrac{t^3}{3}+2t^2+ct$

since t is given as $3s$, Displacement is equal to $9+18+3c = 27 +3c$

Equating it with $30 m$ will give $c=1$

Comment: Thank you, i worked out that the constant was 3, which was marked correct, im an engineer doing a Hnc in college, maths and especially calculus was never my strong point.

Comment: Cheers from a fellow engineer.